# Checkout the files in a changeset to my local workspace

Tags: .net, vb.net, tfs

I am looking into a tf.exe commands that will allow me to checkout all the files to my local workspace from a checked in changeset id. So I can move the changeset from one branch to the other?

Is there any command that will allow me to do that ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the NuGet console, you can use the TFS Powershell Snapin from the TFS PowerTools.

```
Add-PsSnapin Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Powershell
Get-TfsChangeset <ChangesetNumber>
```

Another option is to open Tools > External Tools and add a external tool that calls `TF.exe changeset` and accepts/prompts arguments to supply the changeset number and if you want the other branch name so it can be done completely automatically.

**Edit:** 
If you need to check-out the files you can use:

```
tf checkout .\* /recursive.
```

Ref: [TFS Command-Line Syntax](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/56f7w6be.aspx)

Comment: does that actually checkout the files into my workspace from that changeset?

Comment: Sorry I dont have admin rights atm - I will try it later at home tonight. I've used that command in the past, I recall it did get the files into the wrokspace from the changeset. Can you give it a Bobby? Thanks

Comment: it seems to get the changeset files but in read only state and does not check them out.

Comment: Thanks for that but what I really want to do is checkout all the files in a particular changeset.